# Winforms WebBrowser Control URL Parameters

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I use Visual Studio 2010. I write C# windows application. I wont to use in this application WebBrowser component. I have one problem. I write some address in WebBrowser parameter which have name URL. In result WebBrowser make redirect to another http address. This new address content http string with some parameters. Like this:

http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=9e4b021cb7dd54c795ef1c106f6c0063ef5bc4491f3e6c9e518728b969df58576ebd80dc283e1c7068ac5&expires_in=0&user_id=66476428

I want read the parameter from this new address which have name access_token. But when I trying to get parameter URL of WebBrowser component ( like this

```
MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.Url.ToString());
```

) then I reading only this string:

http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html

How I can to read access_token parameter ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have added the full url to the URL property of the webbrowser1 control? Because if you have then doing .ToString() should give you the complete Url. Can you put a screen shot or code of what you entered in webBrowser1.Url = ???

Comment: Yes, of course. But it is constant url. I write that in propertys panel. See this printscreen:  http://cs308917.userapi.com/v308917428/4d1b/QEYpR7KSkjw.jpg

Answer (score 6):

Try using `webBrowser1.Url.Query` to get the query string part of the uri and then parse the string to get the access_token part.

You can use the [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms150046.aspx) by adding a referenece to System.Web like this

```
var q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(webBrowser1.Url.Query);
var access_token = q["access_token"];
```